# How to know when a View has scrolled into view

Tags: android

We are currently developing an app that displays large data sets in "registers" and in rows. We are using a TableLayout as the base view and then adding table rows for every item (with a LinearLayout in each row).

I have noticed that once the amount of records get beyond a certain point (1000+ records), the device slows down tremendously. I am sure that this is a simple memory issue(maybe rendering too?) and have devised a plan that could increase the speed.

We have implemented continuous paging on a lot of silverlight projects, and I figure that this is the best approach to take in Android?

The only problem I have now is to recognize when a specific view (say row 100) has been scrolled into view, so that I can start to render the next couple of lines.

Does anyone know how to do this, or of a better way to implement/handle large data sets?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using table Layout use CustomListView ,which has the capability of reusing the row.

you can the find how to use Custom list view here.

```
[Custom ListView][1]
```

Comment: Thanks man! Could you perhaps provide the link you spoke about? :D

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add onScrollListener onto your View.
Preferably Use ListView to show data

From the following code your can get the index of the current view.

ListView.OnScrollListener is the interface that you need to implement and give body to
  following two methods.

listView.setOnScrollListener(new ListView.OnScrollListener(){

public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                int totalItemCount) {
        }

```
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        switch (scrollState) {
        case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
            mBusy = false;

            int first = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int count = view.getChildCount();


            break;
        case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:

            break;
        case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:



            break;

        }
    }
```

});

Try Printing the value of first and count variable it will solve your problem.Hopefully :)

Comment: For making it fast try some code for SlowAdapter and EfficientAdapter

Answer (score 0):

I think this video should be very beneficial to you
http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

This talks about the exact problem you are having and how to fix it!